# Eclipse plugin similar to netbeans

Tags: eclipse, plugins

guys. I've been an eclipse user for several months and I don't want to use netbeans because I don't like its interface. Do you have any idea what plugin is this and is this can be added on eclipse? I'll put my example code below.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click");

*//this is the plugin I'm searching for me to be more efficient in creating block of codes*
> button.setBounds(x: 20, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40);
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what your question is. If you are looking for an Eclipse plugin that supports you in developing a user interface with Java Swing, take a look at [Eclipse WindowBuilder](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder). Please note that such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow and better asked on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).